# 'Random' python module inside loops

Tags: python, random, module

I am trying to create a ***python script*** that takes a *string* and adds *random numbers* in *random parts* of the string. For example:

```
str = 'PinguinsAreFun'
output = 'Pi2ngu2in4sAre4F7un'
```

I tried to search for a module that does this very thing but I had no luck. So I thought it would be a good idea to write my own code that will get the job done... Well.. It wasn't a good idea that's for sure...

### This is what I came up with:

```py
import random

num = '0123456789'

str = 'This_Is_A_String'

while k > 15:

    k =+ 1

    rndm = random.choice(num)

    result = str[:int(rndm)] + rndm + str[int(rndm):]

print(result)
```

---

The problem is that it **only works 1 time**. It outputs something like:

```
This_i7s_A_String
```

Since I'm defying `rndm` *inside* the `while` loop I would guess that on every loop its value would change but that doesn't seem to be the case.
It's unlikely that the random value assigned to `rndm` just happened to be the same 15 times :/

So... Any ideas on what's going on?

Comment: how is `k` initialized? and you should not overwrite `str`; then you should re-use `result` (and not your original `str`...). something like `result = 'This_Is_A_String'; ...; result = result[:int(rndm)] + rndm + result[int(rndm):]`

Comment: where is the `k` initialisation ?

Comment: You've wrote `k =+ 1` , it's `k += 1`

Comment: As an aside, don't use `str` as a variable name, as you are shadowing the Python built-in `str`.

Comment: The value of ``rndm`` behaves entirely as you expected. You override the previous value of ``result`` on each iteration step, however...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there are many things wrong in your code:

- `k` is not initialized
- `k =+ 1` should be `k += 1`
- you overwrite the built-in `str`
- you do not re-use the `result` (you just insert one number to the original string)

this is an option to do what you want:

```
from random import randrange

strg = 'This_Is_A_String'
for _k in range(15):
    rndm = randrange(len(strg))
    strg = f'{strg[:rndm]}{rndm}{strg[rndm:]}'

print(strg)
```

Comment: Thank you for pointing out the mistakes. But those were mainly due to me being frustrated :)

Comment: I forgot to write k = 0 in my question, misspelled the '+=' and just wrote a var name without really thinking. My actual code uses 'usr_input  = input('Enter Message: '). Thank you for pointing out the fact that I've been overwriting the result all that time and also thanks for the code provided.

Answer (score 0):

You're using the original string `str` to produce `result` each loop. You should be using the loop's previous `result` to produce the new string each loop.

Answer (score 0):

Try below code, you need to get random positions in your string and then add the random number at that random position of your string.

Easily achievable using below code:

```
import random

num = '0123456789'

mystr = 'This_Is_A_String'
k = 0
while k < len(mystr):
    rndm = random.choice(num)
    randompositioninstring = random.randint(0, len(mystr))
    k += 3
    mystr = mystr[:randompositioninstring] + str(rndm) + mystr[randompositioninstring:]

print(mystr)
```

> Output:
>
> 03Thi57s8_410Is_A8_8108Str6ing48
>
> Process finished with exit code 0

Answer (score 0):

My 2 cents (got rid of `num = '0123456789'`):

```
import random

def rs(string):
    r = string
    for i in range(10):
        index = random.randint(0, len(string))
        r = r[:index] + str(random.randint(0, 9)) + r[index:]
    return r

print(rs('This_Is_A_String'))
```

Output:

```
4T3h1i0s_Is66_9A_6Stri02ng
```